# Parse.com without internet availability in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, timeout, connection-timeout, timeoutexception

I am working on Android application in which I am using parse.com. I am using this code to check internet availability and it is working fine. But if I turn the internet on and make any parse request for example "Check UserName" , and during that request if I stop the 4G or wifi then it will not check internet availability and crash the application.

I want to do something like if I don't get the answer from parse so it should give me TimeOut functionality.

```
private void createUserinfo() {

  if(isNetworkConnected){
        final ParseObject userInfo = new ParseObject("UseIfo");
        userInfo.put("medicote", "");
        userInfo.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
// If i turn the Internet On and and the request, during sending if i again stop
// internet then it will not notifies me like TIME OUT Request or something like this.
        userInfo.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

            ParseUser  user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    user.put("info", userInfo);
                    user.saveInBackground();
                    finishMe();
                }
            }
        });
} else{
      return "No Internet Available";
}
    }


private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni == null) {
        // There are no active networks.
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `sending code` in

```
try{
//here
} catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking for Internet/Network availability before commencing the Parse request, you can use this technique to create the timeout functionality, so that the request doesn't go on interminably: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35255939/2077405